# Current mud tires 35x12.5r15 - can't seem to find the size (all say r15 or r17) - so what do I do now?

Tags: tires, jeep

Just bought a 2005 Wrangler with 35x12.5r16 tires, need to get new tires and can't seem to find the size (all say r15 or r17) - so what do I do now?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Title says r15, but the body says r16. Which is right?

Answer (score 1):

Your Jeep is equipped with aftermarket tires, not stock tires. If  you search for tires based on the vehicle type, you won't find anything, and the 2005 Wrangler (TJ) was never offered with 16" rims.

Don't search by vehicle type, search by tire size. There are several manufacturers that sell tires in this size. I run Yokohamas and Mickey Thompsons, both in that size, and there are dozens of other options.

Most sites will default to searching by vehicle type, but you can search by size. Since most manufacturers use metric sizing, try the metric equivalent 315/75R16 or look at off-road specialty sites like quadratec.com or 4wheelparts.com.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search states that Maxxis manufacture a type known as the Creepy Crawler M8090 in 35x12.5 R16.  I would assume other manufacturers produce similar tyres in the same size.  Within the UK, there are a number of these available.

Searching Amazon just for the tyre size (search criteria "35/12.50R16") turned up an alternative compatible product, a "Super Swamper" as it's very first result.

I am confident that you should be able to locate a supplier for this size.

Your alternative is probably to change the wheels and tyres at the same time to an alternative size (that maintains an equivalent rolling radius).